# eCommerce Conversions Over Attributed to Direct Traffic

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ecommerce, tracking

In Google Analytics, I have about 32% of all transactions attributed to Direct traffic. However, direct traffic only drives about  15% of visits.

Even more puzzling, the ecommerce platform's own analytics attributes about 90% of transactions to direct traffic, and Hubspot does the same.

The tracking snippets are on all pages, but referrer data isn't getting passed along somewhere in the checkout process (I assume).

The website is http, then transitions to https for checkout. However, it's all the same domain. I know GA accounts for transitions like this, and surely Bigcommerce and Hubspot would do the same?

Any ideas on how to debug? Or solutions?

Comment: Last i knew Bigcommerce was forcing its clients to hack together obsolete triggers based on Google ecom tracking from mid 2000's.....before even the async tracking came out. I hope they fixed this by now....but if they didn't (likely), there is the problem...GA prob getting half-baked data :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Universal Analytics with actual ecommerce tracking, not goal tracking. My problem isn't so much with GA, it's with the other tracking methods.